# Crystal Report Parameter - how to stop parameter appearing twice

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I currently have a report which feeds off a stored procedure with the parameters being two date fields i.e. dateto and datefrom.

Now within crystal report and not sql I have created another parameter which asks for the option to select the company the employee belongs to, this can be multiple option or not.

My issue now is that when I run the report the first parameter prompt I get is only the stored procedure parameters, once I input these values another parameter window appears asking for the stored procedure parameters again i.e. the dates but this time also the company parameter.

Is it possible to only have one parameter window prompt with the dates and company parameter appearing once and having to be entered once ?

Comment: Have you created parameters again in report along with stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can check two aspects：

1. There is no subreport in this report.
2. Option "Verify on First Refresh" and "Verify Stored Procedures on First Refresh" are unchecked.